# Finding the most widespread values to keys in dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays

I have dictionary which contains multiple values for keys. I would like to find the top 5 values that cover the most amount of keys. All values only appear once per key. I do not want the most amount of duplicate values, but the 5 values with which their width are the greatest across all keys. So value "abc" may appear in 51 of the 100keys, "def" may appear in 49, 48 of which are in the same keys as "abc", but value "ghi" with 10 keys are in all unqiue keys and should be captured as the top 5 over "def". Hopefully that is clear. I have included my code so far below if it's of any help.

```
with open("all.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

dict1 = dict()

for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    linesplit = line.split(":")
    if linesplit[1] in dict1:
        dict1[linesplit[1]].append(linesplit[0])
    else:
        dict1[linesplit[1]] = [linesplit[0]]
```

Example dict:

```
dog:1,3
cat:2,5
snake:2,4
monkey:3,1
rabbit:3,1
```

As you can see, 1 is in the most keys, the same number of times as 3 and in the same keys, but 2 appears twice in unique keys as the highest duplicate, so it would capture 1 and then 2 as the two highest ranking. So expected output is:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Actually it's not that clear. Please provide some sample input and output, it will be clearer than explaining in long words. As a side note, it's not a good practice to name your variables in names of built-ins (in your case, rename `dict` to, e.g, `dict_`)

Comment: I renamed the dict name for privacy reasons. I have updated my question for further clarity.

Comment: why 3 have lower ranking than 1? Does order matters?

Comment: @MaciejWrobel 3 doesnt need to have lower ranking than 1 if its in the exact same amount of keys and in the same exact keys as 1. Either is fine there :)